# Sublisting list of integers into lists of same integers

Tags: algorithm, list, divide, sublist

Hi I have a simple question. I am grabbing data from an API and the way that they have their data setup is that objects have an id and I return it into a list.

So I will get a list of objects like so:

```
List = {Object1, Object2, Object3, ..., ObjectN};
```

And these objects will have a parent id like so:

```
List = {9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10}
```

I want to sublist the objects into lists containing the same parent id. What would be a decent algorithm to go about accomplishing this? So something like this:

```
Object1's parent id is 9
Object2's parent id is 9
Object3's parent id is 9
Object4's parent id is 10
Object5's parent id is 10
Object6's parent id is 10

List<Object> = {Object1, Object2, Object3} // List of all objects with parent id 9
List<Object> = {Object4, Object5, Object6} // List of all objects with parent id 10
```

I thought about using a `HashMap` as well, is that good practice? For scaling purposes I believe that the list of objects will never amount to anything even over the hundreds, or thousands so I don't think speed is necessarily a HUGE issue here.

Background: Language is in Java, and an Object will have parameters like so:

```
Object: {
    parentId: 
    name:
    //etc.
}
```

Edit: The more I think about this the more I am considering using a sorting algorithm

ANSWER Thanks to SamV:

```
public HashMap<Integer, List<Object>> createHashMap() {
    myHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Object object : mObjectList) {
        int parentId = object.getParentId();
        if (!myHashMap.containsKey(parentId)) {
            List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>();
            myHashMap.put(parentId, newList);
        }

        myHashMap.get(parentId).add(object);
    }

    return myHashMap;
}
```

Comment: So if you have objects and objects have a parentId, it seems using a HashMap to sort the objects is the best solution where the HashMap keys are the parent ID. Loop through the list, and initialise a new HashMap entry with the parent ID as the key and a new list (if the entry does not already exist) and then add the object..

Comment: Your use case screams of using a Map Interface. You might want to consider other implementations such as a TreeMap too .

Comment: What language is this in? And are the lists not returned together, like as one list of objects, where the objects have a parentid property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to above and my correct understanding this is a problem that is solved all the time. The pseudo code would go something like this..

```
fn sortObjects(List objects) {
    var sortedParentHashMap = new HashMap();

    foreach(object in objects) {
        // If the HashMap entry for the current parentId does not exist then initialize
        if (!sortedParentHashMap.exists(object.parentId)) 
            // Initialize the entry with a new list
            sortedParentHashMap.put(object.parentId, new List());
        }
        // Now put the object within the specified parentId list
        sortedParentHashMap.get(object.parentId).put(object);
    }

    return sortedParentHashMap();
}
```

You use the `parentId` of each object to perform the sorting for you. You access the entry of that `parentId` and add the object to the list. If you have duplicates you could make the `new List()` a HashMap to detect duplicates in the same way you would sort via the `parentId`.

HashMaps are usually O(1), so the performance should be high.

Comment: @AndyRoid what programming language are you using? I could provide an example then if I know it..

Comment: I am using Java, but language doesn't matter I can read your example just fine. If you really want to write it in java, that would be pretty cool too

Comment: it works! Thanks for such a quick reply and response, I updated the question with the Java implementation and will go ahead and accept your answer.

Comment: @AndyRoid awesome, hope you understand how it works!

Comment: I totally do, if the hashmap does not contain that parentId then make a new list of objects with that parentId, once the if statement is over go ahead and add it into that list. If it already contains it then it is just one line of code inside the loop. Thanks again SamV!

Comment: Also like that O(1) time, thanks for the performance metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write a Python version anyway.

It uses the defautdict class from the collections model so you can get rid of the if statement within the for loop of the Java example as the first time a key is used in the defaultdict a new empty list is returned as the value.

The equivalent to the Java shown above would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

id2obj = defaultdict(list)
for obj in objects:
    id2obj[obj.parentId].append(obj)
```

If you want to try it out then the small example I wrote, together with class definition is the following:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
from collections import defaultdict

class AnObject():
    def __init__(self, parentId, name):
        self.parentId, self.name = parentId, name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%i)" % (self.name, self.parentId)

objects = [AnObject(id, "Obj%i" % n)
           for n, id in enumerate([9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10], 1)]
print('# OBJECTS')
pp(objects)

id2obj = defaultdict(list)
for obj in objects:
    id2obj[obj.parentId].append(obj)
print('\n# BY ID')
pp(dict(id2obj))
```

The program output is:

```
# OBJECTS
[Obj1(9), Obj2(9), Obj3(9), Obj4(10), Obj5(10), Obj6(10), Obj7(10)]

# BY ID
{9: [Obj1(9), Obj2(9), Obj3(9)], 10: [Obj4(10), Obj5(10), Obj6(10), Obj7(10)]}
```